# Scanner Try Catch Statement results in java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java, error-handling, try-catch

Why is my code giving me an error? If the user entered a wrong number shouldn't the code let me enter a new valid number? Seems as though it doesn't let me change favorite to a new value. How could I get around this problem?

```
package RobB;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class FavoriteNum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] num = new int[10];
        int favorite = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter your favorite number: ");
        try {
            favorite = scan.nextInt();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Enter an integer!");
            System.out.print("Enter your favorite number: ");

            favorite = scan.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a random number (" + Math.abs(((i + 1) - 10)) + " to go): ");
            num[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Enter your favorite number: 11.1

Enter an integer!

Exception in thread "main" Enter your favorite number: java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at RobB.FavoriteNum.main(FavoriteNum.java:21)
```

Comment: _Scan_ in catch ???

Comment: This is the spec - you should take the extra scan you added, and add some while loop until you have a valid input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scanning for input in `catch` clause seems to be not the best idea. I would suggest using a `do-while` loop and the condition allowing to leave this loop could be a `boolean` flag which state would be changed when you confirmed that the valid `Integer` has been finally entered. You might also want to consider using `Scanner`'s `hasNextInt()` method to check if the correct input has been provided, without throwing any exception if it is not really necessary in you case.
Here is a little variation of *ronhash's* answer, but using a `do-while` loop:

```
boolean validInput = false;
do {
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter your favourite number: ");
        favorite = scan.nextInt();
        validInput = true; }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer!"); }
} while (!validInput)
```

Edit: I edited the code because the previous one was inneficient and wrong.

Comment: Thanks, should of thought of this ^^^

Comment: If you find our answers helpful you might want to consider upvoting them, and also if you think any answer covers at all your question you can tick it on the left side as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative with a while loop:

```
boolean validInput = false;
while (!validInput) {
   try {
        System.out.print("Enter your favourite number: ");
        favorite = scan.nextInt();
        validInput = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problems... happy to help, you can also accept the answer :)